# Does using a seperate entitymanagerfactory for each entity cause problems?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I've made a repository class (a class that handles all jpa methods) for each entity type with it's own entitymanagerfactory.
Now I've encountered the following error on my many to many relationship:

`ValidationException
[junit][EclipseLink-7251] Exception Description: The attribute [ID] of class [Person] is mapped to a primary key column in the database. Updates are not allowed.`

This error often doesn't occur anymore when debugging and doesn't seem to appear consistently, which leads me to believe it might be a sync issue between managers. (the Pk is handled by jpa - @Id @GeneratedValue - and never changed by me, i do use cascade merge though)

Am I correct in my current assumption that having multiple entitymanagerfactories is a bad idea (and might be related to my problems)?

Comment: Why would you go about trying to change the ID of an object?! Having multiple EMFs is not going to help (and will kill your performance). Fixing your code is (and you don't present the code that causes the problem).

Comment: I don't want to change the id of the object, I use the @generated to let jpa initialize the id and intend to keep the id as is afterwards.
My thoughtprocess was that because the managers were out of sync, maybe that causes them to want to generate the id a second time thus causing the error.

Comment: So post the CODE that throws an exception and then people can see WHAT is causing it. What (lifecycle) state are the objects in when you perform whatever operation it is?

Comment: an EMF with EclipseLink is just a front to the the shared ServerSession underneath, and so multiple EMFs shouldn't make much difference if they are all using the same classloader and contexts.  Show the code to your error, as reading in through different EMs/EMFs doesn't change anything unless these EMFs are different persistence units and have different mappings for the entities.

Comment: Will do, do I ask that as a separate question? since you answered my original question and my problem is probably unrelated in that case.

Comment: Though I have problems posting the relevant code since the error seems timing-related and doesn't occur in isolation/debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to the conclusion that the different EMFs did in fact cause seperate persistence contexts, which caused problems like the validationException.

(I think this happened when 2 different instances of the same entity were managed in 2 different contexts and one of the instances changed it's state though i'm not certain)

Tested like this:

notes:

- orderweek (= non-owning side) has a one to one bidirectional relationship with week with a cascadeType.ALL.
- orderRep and weekRep are instances executing CRUD statements related to the Db, each with their own entity manager, created from their own EMF
- The 2 EMF's are created in seperate factory-classes, but linked to the same DB and should be using the same Persistence Unit 'BreadPU'.
- I have since realized that multiple EMF's to the same data source is a bad idea

(relevant part of a junit test method)

```
OrderBill cheapOrder = new OrderBill(5, LocalDate.now());
weekRep.addWeek(cheapOrder.getOrderWeek());
//because of the cascade, both the cheapOrder and the week or now persisted in the DB and managed by weekRep

OrderBill dbOrder = orderRep.updateOrder(cheapOrder);
boolean t2 = weekRep.isManaged(cheapOrder); //true
boolean t3  = orderRep.isManaged(cheapOrder); //false
//It's because this returns false I assume both persistence contexts are different
boolean t4 =  orderRep.isManaged(dbOrder); //true
//If i now use "cheapOrder" to change the order i get the error
//If i now use "dbOrder" to change the order, db gets updated as expected
```

Answer (score 1):

EntityManagerFactory represents one persistent unit or in other words one data source. If you don't have multiple datasources then you shouldn't create multipe EMF. You can create multiple EntityManagers though (which you can think of like 'connections' to database).

You create EMF like this -

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
  "objectdb://localhost/myDbFile.odb;user=admin;password=admin")
```

or

```
 EntityManagerFactory emf =
  Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myDbFile.odb");
```

and you create EntityManager like this -

```
 EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

From Javadoc - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html

> Interface used to interact with the entity manager factory for the persistence unit.When the application has finished using the entity manager factory, and/or at application shutdown, the application should close the entity manager factory. Once an EntityManagerFactory has been closed, all its entity managers are considered to be in the closed state.

Adding more, you might need Transactions as well which you would create like this -

```
try {
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    // Operations that modify the database should come here.
    em.getTransaction().commit();
  }
  finally {
    if (em.getTransaction().isActive())
      em.getTransaction().rollback();
  }
```

Comment: I can't accept your answer, since it doesn't really address my initial question, but you do give a good explanation about EMF (and multiple EMF's being bad practice here) among others so you've definitly earned my upvote